# Outlook vsto add-in stores in Drafts folder instead of Deleted Items folder

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I tried to delete contact item with my Outlook VSTO Add-In but the deleted contact item is moved to drafts folder instead of trash folder.

```
public void Delete(Outlook.ContactItem oco)
{
    if (oco != null)
    {
        privateInfo = oco.FullName;
        Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = _Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        if (mapiNamespace != null)
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder trashFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems);
            if (trashFolder != null)
            {
                string folderpath = trashFolder.FolderPath  // to debug only
                oco.Move(trashFolder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The folderpath variable shows the right folder. I develop with Outlook 2016.
I use Microsoft.Office.Iterop V15.0.4420.1017.

Who can explain this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Are there any rules or VBA macro, or COM add-ins running in Outlook who could move an item to another folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to delete contact item with my Outlook VSTO Add-In but the deleted contact item is moved to drafts folder instead of trash folder.

In the code you move an item passed as an argument to the `Deleted Items` folder. Use the [ContactItem.Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.contactitem.delete) method which removes the item from the folder that contains the item. The `Delete` method moves the item from the containing folder to the `Deleted Items` folder. If the containing folder is the `Deleted Items` folder, the `Delete` method removes the item permanently.